# Indefinite integral of absolute value given x(0)

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value

*edited- the mistake was I took $\sqrt{2x-3}$ and not $\sqrt{3-2x}$. When you take the correct one you get: $$(t-c)^2 = 3 - 2x$$ $$ c=\sqrt3$$ $$=> x = \sqrt3t-{t^2\over2}$$
$$---------------------------------------$$
I have this equation: $$x'(t)=\sqrt{|2x-3|}$$ and $$x(0)=0$$ I have to find the semi-regular
solution of this ODE. Because $x(0)=0$ I know that $x < 1.5$ for all $t$.So my integral is :
$$t = \int{{dx\over\sqrt{2x-3}}}$$  $$=> t = (2x-3)^{1\over2}+c$$
And here I am a bit stuck because I get $$({t} - {c})^2 = 2x-3$$  $$({t} - {c})^2 + 3 = 2x$$but $x(0)=0$ and the left side is always greater than $0$... How do I proceed from here?

Comment: You are on the wrong branch. Try $\sqrt{3-2x}$ instead.

Comment: Near $t=0$ we have $2x-3<0$.  But $2x-3$ can change sign later.

Comment: The absolute value ;$|2x-3|=3-2x$  for $x<1.5$ this changes the integral $t = \int{{dx\over\sqrt{3-2x}}}$

Comment: @Klaus thank you!